# Warning: CSS type selectors are not supported in components 'sparks.component.TextInput'

Tags: css, apache-flex, types, flex-spark

I am trying to do a simple CSS declaration. However, I have got the warning above and not sure how to solve it. I thought s|(type) should declare the style for me.

```
<fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        s|TextInput{
        color:#313131;
        }           
</fx:Style>

<s:Panel width="600" height="480" skinClass="skins.CustomPanel">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="7"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:TextInput text="TextInput CSS not working"/>
    <mx:Form>
        <mx:FormHeading label="Please Enter The Information"/>
        <s:HGroup>
            <mx:FormItem>
                <s:Label text="Brand"/>
                <s:TextInput id="brand" text="CSS not working" width="156"/>
            </mx:FormItem>
    </mx:form>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

CSS Type selectors are not allowed inside a component definition.

You have two options :

- Use a class selector instead
- Move the Type selector declaration in a css that is declared in your top MXML file

Comment: Man..no books ever mention that! All they say is how great type selector is but never mention its not supported in component. I was looking for the answer for a while. I guess I will follow your suggestion. Thanks!