# adobe flash builder 4: css type selectors are not supported in components spark.components.Label

Tags: css, label, flex4, flash-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: css type selectors are not supported in components ‘sparks.component.TextInput’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125364/warning-css-type-selectors-are-not-supported-in-components-sparks-component-te)

I created a new MXML component that contains some labels and the following style:

```
<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
    @namespace local "*";
    s|Label {
        font-size:12;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:white;
    }
    #timeLeftHGroup {
        left:30;
        top:12;
    }
```

I get the following warning at the `s|Label` line:

```
CSS type selectors are not supported in components: 'spark.components.Label'
```

Well.. the CSS code does work! it did change the color, make the text bold and changed the font size to 12, so why do i get this warning ?

Answer (score 1):

s| is ignored as it's not supported when used inside of a component. Try putting it in a root level style sheet which is applied to the entire application.